# cd into all directories, execute command on files in that directory, and return to previous current directory

Tags: shell-script

I'm attempting to write a script that will be run in a given directory with many single level sub directories. The script will cd into each of the sub directories, execute a command on the files in the directory, and cd out to continue onto the next directory. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

```
for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && somecommand); done
```

Comment: So since the answerer has omitted any sort of explanation, I'll attempt one. `for d in ./*/` starts a loop that stores every item in `./*/` (a list of files/folders, in this case) in a variable `$d`. `do (cd "$d" && somecommand);` starts the body of the loop. Inside the body, it starts a [subshell](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) and runs the `cd` and `somecommand` commands. Since it is a child shell, the parent shell (the shell from which you're running this command) retains its CWD and other environment variables. `done` simply closes the loop body.

Comment: this methodworks for sub directories of directories:   
`for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && ls); done` ,will not work. but,
`for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && ls); done
); done` will work. -using ls as the command in this example.

Comment: `-bash: cd: ./*/: No such file or directory`

Comment: if you need nested level, Ref: https://superuser.com/a/1132088/553982

Answer (score 26):

The best way is to not use `cd` at all:

```
find some/dir -type f -execdir somecommand {} \;
```

`execdir` is like `exec`, but the working directory is different:

```
-execdir command {} [;|+]
  Like   -exec,   but  the  specified  command  is  run  from  the
  subdirectory containing the matched file, which is not  normally
  the  directory  in  which  you  started  find.  This a much more
  secure  method  for  invoking  commands,  as  it   avoids   race
  conditions  during resolution of the paths to the matched files.
```

It is not POSIX.

Comment: Does this work with aliases? I have one to download certain files but it isn't recognizing it when I type in

find */.link -type f -execdir md $(cat .link) {} \;

Comment: @SomethingJones no, `find` executes those commands, so it wouldn't be aware of aliases. What is `md` and is the `.link` a directory?

Comment: .link is a text file that has the URL it needs to download. md is an alias to wget with a bunch of flags set. Is there a way to make it aware of aliases?

Comment: @SomethingJones For your particular use-case, in `bash`: `find . -type f -iname '*.link' -execdir ${BASH_ALIASES[md]} -i {} \;` You don't need to do `cat` with `wget`, which has an `-i` flag for reading in an URL from a file. Also this is somewhat different from your original question (since you seem to be interested in only files named `.link` and not any other files which may be present).

Comment: Do you know how to do that with zsh? I tried what you gave me and am getting a "Bad substitution" error. Also, how would I be able to extract the content of the .link file? I know I don't need it in this case but I imagine I will soon.

Comment: Can you show an example of a dangerous or insecure race condition that the manpage warns about? Or does that warrant a new question?

Comment: @hexafraction The [GNU documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Problems-with-_002dexec-and-filenames) discusses it. The example given of a dangerous condition would be a filename starting with `-`. The  race condition given is renaming the directory once a test is done (e.g., `-prune`).

Comment: Some further explanation would be helpful. When I try this with an echo command, it echoes every file in the subdirectories, not just the top-level directory names themselves. I tried it with `find ./* ...`

Comment: problems with this in msys `find: The relative path ‘C’ is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove that entry from $PATH`

Answer (score 7):

```bsh
for D in ./*; do
    if [ -d "$D" ]; then
        cd "$D"
        run_something
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cd -P .
for dir in ./*/
do cd -P "$dir" ||continue
   printf %s\\n "$PWD" >&2
   command && cd "$OLDPWD" || 
! break; done || ! cd - >&2
```

The above command doesn't need to do any subshells - it just tracks its progress in the current shell by alternating `$OLDPWD` and `$PWD`. When you `cd -` the shell exchanges the value of these two variables, basically, as it changes directories. It also prints the name for each directory as it works there to stderr.

I just had a second look at it and decided I could do a better job with error handling. It will skip a dir into which it cannot `cd` - and `cd` will print a message about why to stderr - and it will `break` w/ a non-zero exit code if your `command` does not execute successfully or if running `command` somehow affects its ability to return to your original directory - `$OLDPWD`. In that case it also does a `cd -` last - and writes the resulting current working directory name to stderr.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 :**

```
for i in `ls -d ./*/`
do
  cd "$i"
  command
  cd ..
done
```

**Method 2 :**

```
for i in ./*/
do
  cd "$i"
  command
  cd..
done
```

**Method 3 :**

```
for i in `ls -d ./*/`
do
  (cd "$i" && command)
done
```

I hope this was useful. You can try all permutation and combinations on this.

**Thanks** :)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note, however, that parsing the output of `ls` is [highly disrecommended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) as it can stumble on directory names with whitespace or other special characters, so promoting method 1 and 3 without a warning might not be a good idea.